# Почему не видит библиотеку android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat?

Tags: java, android

Странная проблема появилась не от куда.

Работал проект нормально и вдруг во всех классах где использовался вот такой импорт

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
```

Начало показывать, что не может распознать, что это такое...

Проверил `.gradle` там все в порядке

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

Сделал ребилд проекта, закрыл открыл студию... Ничего не помогает...

В строках где я пользовался этим классом, так как тут например

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity.getApplicationContext(), permission) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

теперь при нажатии <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> предлагает добавить библиотеку

```
import android.support.v13.app.ActivityCompat;
```

Кто может подсказать, что тут происходит? Почему не видит нужную библиотеку?

Comment: Наверное гугл обновил либы поддержки и вынес этот класс в либу v13. А вы обновили все либы поддержки и теперь ваш класс в другой либе. По идее вам надо таки как и предлагает студия подключить `compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.1'`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да но там нет этого метода `checkSelfPermission()` , который я использую... И к тому же я не обновлял номер версии... Но все равно только, что попробовал понизить номер версии на 2 и все равно та же ошибка...

Comment: Хм... Странно... Может у вас студия последняя и вы в ней ещё один баг нашли? Попробуйте `Invalidate cache and restart` студии сделать и\или поставить более старую версию студии

Comment: Посмотрите ещё тут. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407250/checkselfpermission-method-is-not-working-in-targetsdkversion-22?noredirect=1&lq=1 Может надо попробовать PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission и/или окружить эти строки проверками на текущую версию оси

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да может, но тогда почему когда я откатываюсь на пару git tag назад то все билдится...

Comment: Ну, значит вы что-то где изменили не так... Попробуйте найти коммит после коего всё испортилолось и там надо искать ошибку. Думаю она где-то в градл

Comment: @ЮрийСПб очень странно но только что все заработало... Я переключился еще раз с ветки на ветки на ветку, сделал ребилд и порядок... Но когда написал `git status` показало , что модифицирован вот такой файл `.idea/vcs.xml` ...  Странные вещи тут происходят)) Но все равно спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Я переключился еще раз с ветки на ветки на ветку, сделал ребилд и порядок... Но когда написал git status показало , что модифицирован вот такой файл .idea/vcs.xml ... Странные вещи тут происходят))

В этом файле продублировалась вот такая строка

```
<mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="Git" />
```

теперь файл выглядит вот так

```
<project version="4">
      <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
        <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="Git" />
+   <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="Git" />
      </component>
    </project>
\ No newline at end of file
```

Честно я даже не знаю, зачем нужен этот файл...

Comment: Вообще все файлы из `.idea` надо бы в игнор добавлять) Думаю, будет неплохо, если вы добавите сюда или в вопрос что именно там поменялось - может будет понятно в чём была проблема)

Comment: Так этот файл наверняка был в игноре, я первый раз его увидел в отслеживаемых... Добавил в ответ изменения